# iOS still able to reference files after I remove them

Tags: ios, uiimage

I feel dumb for asking this, but I've spent like two hours trying to figure it out. I have a bunch of pictures that I included in my xcode project. I have them named `background1.png`, `background2.png`, `background3.png` etc.. I was renaming & messing around with the numbers of the photos and whatnot, and for some reason when I ran my code and I called `[UIImage imagenamed @"background7.png"]` I was getting `background9.png` instead. So I figured I have duplicate images in my project somewhere.

I deleted all the background images that I can find in my project. And when I run the code, even though I think they should all be gone, these images are still showing up. I opened up the finder and deleted any reference of `background*.png` I can find on my entire computer, and I tried moving the project to a different directory and it is still finding these photos. I thought that maybe the simulator/phone is caching the images so I deleted the app, didn't help. Any ideas on where these images might be hiding to where I can't find them anywhere but they can still be referenced?

Comment: Do a cleanup on your project. Press command + K and then build again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to follow two simple steps :-

1. Clean your project. (Xcode->Product->Clean)
2. Delete application from device/simulator

Run again.

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Perfect. I've been doing iOS for about 8 months now and still get caught up on week one programming tips.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts Did it solved your issue. If yes, accept answer as this helps others to refer too!

Comment: Yeah, I just had to wait seven minutes before it would let me accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean and build the project again. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then run(<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) the code again. You can also try resetting the simulator or remove the app from there. If you are using device, you can remove the app from there.